# Create two influxdb from docker compose YAML file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, influxdb

I want to create two database while running `docker-compose up` command.
Below is the solution I have tried but didn't worked

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb
    env_file: configuration.env
    ports:
      - '8086:8086'
    volumes:
      - 'influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb'
    environment:
      - INFLUXDB_DB=testDB
    command: sh -c Sample.sh
```

Error which I am getting `influxdb_1_170f324e55e3 | sh: 1: Sample.sh: not found`
Inside Sample.sh I have curl command which when executed standalone creates another db.

Comment: where you copy the `Sample.sh` in the container ?

Comment: @LinPy I have placed in location were my docker-compose.yml file is present.

Comment: yes but you did not copy the file to the Container. `command` in compose will run in the container not on the host

Comment: @LinPy I am new to Docker so pardon me. so does that mean't I have to copy that sh file while preparing image inside Dockerfile?

Comment: see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not override the run command of the influx DB container, if you overide the `CMD` then you need to start the `influxd` process as well. So better to go with init.db script and populate the script at run time.

**Initialization Files**

> If the Docker image finds any files with the extensions `.sh` or
>   `.iql` inside of the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder, it will
>   execute them. The order they are executed in is determined by the
>   shell. This is usually alphabetical order.

**Manually Initializing the Database**

> To manually initialize the database and exit, the `/init-influxdb.sh`
>   script can be used directly. It takes the same parameters as the
>   influxd run command. As an example:

```
$ docker run --rm \
      -e INFLUXDB_DB=db0 -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true \
      -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword \
      -e INFLUXDB_USER=telegraf -e INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=secretpassword \
      -v $PWD:/var/lib/influxdb \
      influxdb /init-influxdb.sh
```

As you check the entrypoint of [influx DB offical image](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdata-docker/blob/2bc2bfe36b6b7cadf8221b5198774b3d50b11dc3/influxdb/1.6/alpine/entrypoint.sh) and you can explore the [database initialization](https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb) from the offical page.

So you need place you script in `.iql` or `.sh` and mount the location in docker-compose.

```
    volumes:
      - 'influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb'
      - init.db/init.iql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Better to create using [InfluxQL](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/database_management/), add below line to your script and save as `init.iql`

```
CREATE DATABASE "NOAA_water_database"
```

You need to update Dockerfile as well.

```
FROM influxdb
COPY init.iql  /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

now you can remove the command from CMD and it should create DB

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  influxdb:
    build: .
    env_file: configuration.env
    ports:
      - '8086:8086'
    volumes:
      - 'influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb'
    environment:
      - INFLUXDB_DB=testDB
```

Comment: the compose need to build the image not getting it from influxdb

Comment: yes you need to build first to have script in the image `docker-compose up -d --build`

Comment: no i mean you must change your answer in the compose to use build

Comment: oh Sorry. Thanks @LinPy you can update my answer and I will approve :)